# How can I view different pages in browser while coding (Vue)?

Tags: vue.js

I'm working on a few different pages as well as components. How can I view each individual page in the browser while I am working on it (to see how it looks)? Can I do this before implementing router and if so how?

Comment: try https://codepen.io/

Comment: codesandbox.io or codepen.io should be useful